# matlab: delimit .csv file where no specific delimiter is available

Tags: matlab, delimiter

i wonder if there is the possibility to read a .csv file looking like:

`0,0530,0560,0730,....
90,15090,15290,157....`

i should get:

`0,053 0,056 0,073 0,...
90,150 90,152 90,157 90,...`

when using `dlmread(path, '')` matlab spits out an error saying 
`Mismatch between file and Format character vector.
Trouble reading 'Numeric' field frin file (row 1, field number 2) ==> ,053  0,056 0,073 ...`

i also tried using "0," as the delimiter but matlab prohibits this.

Thanks,
jonnyx

Comment: Do you mean you want the comma `,` as a decimal separator sometimes, and as the field separator other times ? I think you'd better treat your CSV first with some kind of shell script, or seeks a way to have properly formatted values first.

Comment: @Pac0 it looks even worse, like the `,` should always be a decimal separator and the delimiter is whatever number comes after the 3rd decimal value (thousandths)

Comment: The only way to read this would be to use string manipulation on every row. As there is no delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do this using [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) without any loops and using a few basic string manipulation functions:

```
fid = fopen('no_delim.csv', 'r');
C = textscan(fid, ['%[0123456789' 10 13 ']%[,]%3c'], 'EndOfLine', '');
fclose(fid);
C = strcat(C{:});
output = strtrim(strsplit(sprintf('%s ', C{:}), {'\n' '\r'})).';
```

And the output using your sample input file:

```
output =

  2×1 cell array

    '0,053 0,056 0,073'
    '90,150 90,152 90,157'
```

### How it works...

The [format string](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec) specifies 3 items to read repeatedly from the file:

- A string containing any number of characters from 0 through 9, newlines (ASCII code 10), or carriage returns (ASCII code 13).
- A comma.
- Three individual characters.

Each set of 3 items are [concatenated](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html), then all sets are [printed to a string](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) separated by spaces. The [string is split](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) at any newlines or carriage returns to create a cell array of strings, and any spaces on the ends are [removed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I got it now like I wanted it!
after using the textscan function, i got an cell of some Dimension like 2000x1 which i could not plot like that as the cell was formatted as a string. furthermore, both my columns where concatenated into one column:
`C = textscan(fid, ['%[0123456789]%[,]%3c'], 'delimiter', '\n');
 fclose(fid);
 C = strcat(C{:});
 length = length(C);
 force = C(1:length/2);
 distance = C(length/2+1:length);
 force = cellfun(@str2double,force);
 distance = cellfun(@str2double,distance);`
solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

```
str= importdata('file.csv','');   %importing the data as a cell array of char
for k=1:length(str)               %looping till the last line
    str{k}=myfunc(str{k});        %applying the required operation
end
```

where

```
function new=myfunc(str)
  old = str(1:regexp(str, ',', 'once'));  %finding the characters till the first comma
                                              %old is the pattern of the current line
  new=strrep(str,old,[' ',old]);  %adding a space before that pattern
  new=new(2:end);                 %removing the space at the start
end
```

and **file.csv** :

```
0,0530,0560,073
90,15090,15290,157
```

---

**Output:**

```
>> str

str=

    '0,053 0,056 0,073'
    '90,150 90,152 90,157'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solves the Problem of splitting the concatenated strings.
I still had issues working with the resulting `str` as i could not convert this string to numbers without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a GNU / *NIX command line, I would suggest using `sed` to **preprocess** your data before feeding into matlab. The command would be in this case : `sed 's/,[0-9]\{3\}/& /g'` .

```
$ echo "90,15090,15290,157" | sed 's/,[0-9]\{3\}/& /g'

90,150 90,152 90,157

$ echo "0,0530,0560,0730,356" | sed 's/,[0-9]\{3\}/& /g'

0,053 0,056 0,073 0,356
```

also, you easily change commas `,` to decimal point `.`

```
$ echo "0,053 0,056 0,073 0,356" | sed 's/,/./g'

0.053 0.056 0.073 0.356
```